# Radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

What is radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}z^n$?

I don't know anything

Comment: If, as you claim, *you don't know anything*, why are you even interested in solving this exercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radius of convergence is given by $\dfrac{1}{R}= \lim_{n \to \infty}  |a_n|^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$

$\therefore$ $\dfrac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right]^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$=$\dfrac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e$

$\therefore R=\dfrac{1}{e}$